# PHP Content form will not submit email and shows php code in browser

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

I used this tutorial as a guide to create a simple contact form. I am new to using php and this seemed easy enough to figure out, but there seems to be some bugs in the code. After implementing the code on my site, the submit button brings me to a page displaying all of my php code in the browser and no email is sent.

```
$email_to =   'skustrimovic@gmail.com<script type="text/javascript"> 
/* <![CDATA[ */ 
(function(){try{var s,a,i,j,r,c,l=document.getElementById("__cf_email__");a=l.className;if(a){s='';r=parseInt(a.substr(0,2),16);for(j=2;a.length-j;j+=2){c=parseInt(a.substr(j,2),16)^r;s+=String.fromCharCode(c);}s=document.createTextNode(s);l.parentNode.replaceChild(s,l);}}catch(e {}})(); 
/* ]]> */ 
</script>'; //the address to which the email will be sent  
$name     =   $_POST['name'];  
$email    =   $_POST['email'];  
$subject  =   $_POST['subject'];  
$message  =   $_POST['message'];  

    /*the $header variable is for the additional headers in the mail function, 
 we are asigning 2 values, first one is FROM and the second one is REPLY-TO. 
 That way when we want to reply the email gmail(or yahoo or hotmail...) will know 
 who are we replying to. */  
$headers  = "From: $email\r\n";  
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email\r\n";  

if(mail($email_to, $subject, $message, $headers)){  
    echo 'sent'; // we are sending this text to the ajax request telling it that the mail is sent..  
}else{  
    echo 'failed';// ... or this one to tell it that it wasn't sent  
}
```

Should I just try to create my own PHP to work the existing HTML/jquery?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Come on. You're asking people to debug a tutorial. At least post the code that is giving you the issue. (hint: start with the PHP code)

Comment: Is this on your local machine?  If so, do you have a webserver installed?

Comment: yes this is on my local machine, a web server is not installed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `send_email.php` script on that tutorial site doesn't have a `<?php` opening . . . that might be your issue?

Alternatively, you'll want to make sure that basic PHP code can run on your server, e.g. a simple helloworld.php:

```
<?php
    echo "hello world"
?>
```

If not, you'll need to troubleshoot as to why PHP is not running - e.g. is the webserver running, is php installed, etc.

Comment: There is a <?php opening and closing.....

Can I test to see if the email is sent successfully by previewing from dreamweaver?

Comment: Not with just dreamweaver.  You'll still need a PHP dev environment on your machine: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/articles/setup_php.html

Comment: got it, so that probably is the reason for the browser displaying the php code in the browser when i preview from dreamweaver

Comment: yes, php runs server side (as opposed to javascript which runs client side in the browser), so you need a web server with php for the code to run properly

Comment: awesome, thank you for helping out the new kid. Your input was a huge help